# Issue when creating files using python in vim

Tags: filetype-python

When writing or appending files using python inside vim, new files are not being created and existing files are not being changed. Creating and appending files in python script and atom text editor are working, it's only in vim where it doesn't work.

I'm guessing it could be a permission issue or a bad path but I've tried using an absolute path which didn't help.

Not sure where to look or where to change permission. 
I can add my .vimrc if needed or plugins.

Here is the python code - i use `try` to show there is no input/output error:

```
from pathlib2 import Path

p = Path('/Users/plutonium/Documents/Programs/Python/File')
q = p / 'a.ext'

try:
    with open(q,'w') as f:
        f.write('content')
except IOError:
    print('I/O Error...') # no error
finally:
    print('checked')
```

Comment: How are you running this? Do you see the “checked” output?

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble yes, it runs smoothly in python script and atom. its just in vim where it doesn't. not sure what is conflicting with it. maybe a permission issue? Although, i can't figure out what to look for or where.

Comment: How are you running this in Vim

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble not sure what you mean. I guess to see the output i add this command in vim. `:!python3 %`

Comment: it runs it in python script. It just doesn't create or append the files when using vim.

Comment: Cant reproduce. Your script runs fine for me using `:!python3 %`